# Encountered unsupported property SourceSecurityGroupId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to construct a template for AWS::CloudFormation where create a RDS. But when I trying to launch the model, I get a `Encountered unsupported property SourceSecurityGroupId`.

I use this parameters to get the security group id

```
"WebServerSecurityGroupId": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id",
}
```

And the resource I use:

```
"Resources": {
    "DBVPCSecurityGroup" : {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties" : {
            "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
             "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
                {
                    "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                    "FromPort" : "80",
                    "ToPort" : "80",
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId:" : {
                        "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroupId"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
// the rest of template
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually looks good. Could you try to separate the Security group with Ingress:

```
"DBVPCSecurityGroup" : {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
    }
},
"WebServerSecurityHTTPIn": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
            "Ref": "DBVPCSecurityGroup"
        },
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "80",
        "ToPort": "80",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
            "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroupId"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: it works, right now is create the RDS Instance. just like I want it.

Thanks